# Ejecutar codigo PHP dentro de Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Me podrían ayudar co un problema:

Deseo ejecutar código *PHP* dentro de *Javascript*.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <?php echo "hola como estan"; ?>);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

La salida html:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        hola como estan <-- marcado en rojo en el inspector del navegador
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

El error en la consola del navegador:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: Has probado a hacer algo como `alert("<?php echo "hola como estan"; ?>");` Si no es estrictamente necesario, no uses fotos para mostrar algo que se puede ver con código.

Comment: @Javier De preferencia que el código y errores sean texto

Comment: Hola espero estes bien 1. Para que deseas ejecutar código php de esa manera ?
2. Si lo que deseas es traer información generada por tu código php y usarla en javascript te recomiendo mejor realizar tu backend en php y traer la información por medio de peticiones http, ajax , etcetera... parcearla e utilizarla en tu js, es la práctica mas común y existen diversas librerías de js como: https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actualmente yo mando así

```
    $.post("<?php echo URL ?>/enviarRevisionDocumental",
```

o dime mas sobre tu inquietud con gusto te ayudo.

Answer (score 10):

Creo que hay un error de concepto a la hora de estructurar la tarea que quieres hacer.

Realmente no se ejecuta *PHP* dentro de *Javascript*, sino que *Javascript* hará uso de lo que *PHP* imprima dentro de sus etiquetas o funciones. Dado que *PHP* es lenguaje de servidor, se ejecutará antes que *Javascript*.

Básico para que se entienda, el orden en el que se ejecutan:

**1º** *PHP* (servidor)
**2º** *HTML* (navegador)
**3º** *Javascript* (navegador)

Entonces el flujo iría de la siguiente forma:

1.- ¿Qué resultado queremos conseguir?

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <script>
       alert("hola como estan"); 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

2.- ¿Qué parte de ese resultado va a gestionar *PHP*?

```
hola como estan
```

3.- ¿Cómo imprime *PHP* este texto dentro de *html*?

```
<?php echo "hola como estan"; ?>
```

4.- ¿Cómo se pone todo en funcionamiento?

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <script>
       alert("<?php echo "hola como estan"; ?>");
       //    ^                                ^
       //   (1)                              (2)
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

> Ojo con la sintaxis, las comillas de *Javascript* hay que mantenerlas.

#### Un ejemplo sencillo:

```
<?php
// varios textos en un array
$txt = array(
    "Hola como estan",
    "Hola que tal va",
    "Hola ke ase XD",
);
// desordena el contenido del array
shuffle($txt);
?>

<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <script>
       // cada vez que recarga el navegador
       // debería lanzar el texto de forma 
       // aleatoria
       alert("<?php echo $txt[0]; ?>"); 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Para ampliar, creo que es importante mencionar que si los contenidos que se imprimen dentro de la etiqueta script provienen de un usuario (por ejemplo a través de un formulario) y no se tratan correctamente, es posible que se genere allí una vulnerabilidad XSS: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Por ejemplo, si ponéis al principio del ejemplo `$txt = ["Hola\"); while(true) { alert(); } alert(\"];`, veréis que hemos inyectado un trozo de código Javascript que ejecuta un bucle infinito.

Answer (score 2):

Asi como lo tienes es un error de sintaxis.  Si quieres escribir algo puedes usar la consola asi:

```
<?php echo "console.log('hola como estan');"
```

O tambien un alert asi:

```
<?php echo "alert('hola como estan');"
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar type (nota el uso de type="php" en el script que contiene código php). El ejemplo es muy inseguro porque usa eval sin filtro, así que cuidado.
(Básicamente es lo que usan bibliotecas como Babel):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['ev']) && $_POST['ev']=='1' && isset($_POST['que']) && !empty($_POST['que'])){
    eval($_POST['que']);
    exit;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>test</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <script type="php">
        echo 'hola, hoy es '.date('d-m-Y');
        </script>
        <script>
        function request(url,callback,params){
            var H=new XMLHttpRequest();
            if(!H)return;
            var p='';
            for(var i in params){
                p+='&'+i+'='+encodeURIComponent(params[i]); 
            }
            var signo=url.indexOf('?')==-1 ? '?' :'&';
            H.open('post',url+signo+Math.random(),true);
            H.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            H.onreadystatechange=function(){
                if(H.readyState==4 && (H.status == 200 ||  H.status==0) ){
                    if(callback)callback(H.responseText);
                    H.onreadystatechange=function(){}
                    H.abort();
                    H=null;
                }
            }
            H.send(p);
        }
        var scs=[].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('script'));
        scs.forEach(
            function(sc){
                if(sc.type=='php'){
                    request(
                        '?',
                        function(r){
                            sc.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(r),sc);
                        },
                        {'ev':'1','que':sc.text}
                    );
                }
            }
        );
        </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

En el código del script tú lo habías puesto como:

```
<script>
    <?php echo 'Hola mundo'; ?>
</script>
```

Ahí el problema, al poner echo haces que el navegador quite las etiquetas php y pone solo el hola mundo. Lo que tienes que hacer tendrías que mezclar código php con js.
Por ejemplo:
Si quieres hacer que salga un console.log tienes que hacer lo
siguiente.

```
<script>
    console.log('<?php echo 'Hola mundo';?>');
</script>
```

Comment: Eliminé el enlace a tu canal pues no parece tener contenido relevante a la pregunta o la comunidad y parece que solo es spam, por favor lee [answer]