# Como implementar php en javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Bueno tengo una pregunta que realmente no sé cómo empezar.
Estoy haciendo una web y tiro de una base de datos y los muestro por php.

Ahora viene mi problema en una página que estoy usando javascript puedo seleccionar un producto de cuatro.
Mi gran problema es que no sé cómo implementar código php con javascript.

Os dejo una parte del código.
Si realizo esto me funciona pero quiero sacar los datos por php.

```
p1_1=1;
p1_1n="paella";
p1_1p="3.45";
p1_1i="jj";

Este es el codigo que tira de BD
p1_1=1;
p1_1n="<?php echo $row_menuD['plato']; ?>";

p1_1p="2.75";
p1_1i="<?php echo $row_menuD['strImagen1'];?>";
```

Y suponiendo que esto funcionara tengo este otro codigo de javascript y tambien necesito implementar php.

```
{
if (platoseleccionado==1)
    {
        $("#plato1_2").slideUp("slow");
        $("#plato1_3").slideUp("slow");
        $("#plato1_4").slideUp("slow");
        $("#bloqueimagenes1").slideDown("slow");
        $("#plato1_1").slideDown("slow");
        sessionStorage.plato1=p1_1;
        sessionStorage.plato1nombre=p1_1n;
        sessionStorage.plato1precio=p1_1p;
        sessionStorage.plato1imagen=p1_1i;
    }
```

```
sessionStorage.plato1="";
sessionStorage.plato1nombre="";
sessionStorage.plato1precio="";
sessionStorage.plato1imagen="";
```

```
textopedido="";
textopedido='Primer Plato: '+sessionStorage.plato1nombre+'<br><img src="/images/productos/'+sessionStorage.plato1imagen+'" width="120px"><br>';
```

Pero no sé cómo hacerlo muchísimas gracias

Comment: Esto responde a tu pregunta? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/159529/ejecutar-codigo-php-dentro-de-javascript

Comment: ¿Qué es exactamente lo que necesitas hacer con PHP? No basta con _también necesito implementar php_.

Comment: Gracias. Si la verdad me lio bastante.

Comment: Quiero sacar datos de una BD y poder pasar esos datos a javascript. Que es justamente lo que no se. Estoy tambien pensando en no hacerme tanto lio e intentar conectarme a esa BD por medio de javascript estoy en ello.Muchas gracias